# Returning unique rows in report builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services

apologies if this is a bit long...
I'm building a report in Report Builder 3 from a SQL 2012 db to display a list of results from a disk space check. The check runs every two minutes so obviously it returns a lot of duplicate results. Is there a way to only return the results that show when the disk space has changed? Here's the query I'm using and the results it gets

```
SELECT V.iValue AS 'Result', V.iDate AS 'Date/Time'
FROM DataValues V  
WHERE idate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ORDER BY iDate DESC

 Date/Time     Result    
  ...11:06     223
  ...11:04     223
  ...11:02     222  etc
```

After a lot of looking around I've managed to change the query to this

```
    SELECT V.iValue AS 'Result', V.iDate AS 'Date/Time' FROM DataValues V 
    WHERE V.iValue IN (SELECT V.iValue FROM DataValues V GROUP BY V.iValue HAVING
    COUNT(V.iValue)=1) AND F.iScale = 8 
    AND idate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate ORDER BY iDate DESC
```

Which only returns results where there were no duplicates recorded. I need to filter out rows where there are more than one of the same result, but keep the first row where that result was recorded. Does anyone have any advice?
(There are some joins in the actual query which I wouldn't have thought are relevant here but can post the full thing if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a ROW_NUMBER function, partitioned by Result and ordered by Date/Time.

Then I would wrap the entire SELECT in an outer SELECT or use a CTE, and then filter where ROW_NUMBER Result = 1.